# How do I put a icon on java applications?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, icons, executable-jar

I have a question. I have a really cool game that I have made in eclipse. In order for people to execute it I want to convert it to a executable jar. Although I want the jar to have a icon like most .exe programs, although I don't know how to do that. What is the way that most people put icons on their java programs? I have converted it to a .exe with a icon before but I want to know if there is another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar is not really an executable from the OS point of view - it is just an archive of compiled classes and resources. But there is a way to accomplish what you wish for. **You have to use executable wrapper.**

Here are few of them:

JSmooth: http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/

Launch4j: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

JWrapper: http://www.jwrapper.com/java-to-exe-free.html

Answer (score 0):

[Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html) will allow you to do this.  It offers many advantages, including handling automatic updates and even integration with the desktop's application menu (which is the Start menu in Windows).  One of its biggest advantages, in my opinion, is that it comes with every Java installation, so no third-party libraries are required.