# Changing Destop Icon For An Executable Jar FIle (in the code of couse)

Tags: java, icons

After trawling website after website, I haven't found an answer... however, all the answers ive found on stack overflow have been for frames... i'm farely new with java... so I'm using JOptionPanes. I can't seem to find a way in the code to  change the cup of java to a custom image. Thanks!

Comment: You can't, basically, the icon is supplied by the file association within the OS, you couldn't change the icons shown by the OS for a Word Document.  You could create a shortcut, but this OS specific and would require some JNI/JNA or you could create an executable wrapper, which would allow you to specify the icon of the executable, but again, this is OS specific

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289511/how-do-i-put-a-icon-on-java-applications/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike a .exe file a .jar has no independent icon. You cannot change the icon of a .jar without changing the icon of all .jar files in your computer.

You could use [**JSmooth**](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net).

> JSmooth is a Java Executable Wrapper. It creates native Windows
>   launchers (standard .exe) for your java applications. It makes java
>   deployment much smoother and user-friendly, as it is able to find any
>   installed Java VM by itself.